# How Can I save my customer

Tags: magento2

who can help me with this issue we can't save the customer
[image]

Comment: What about the log ?

Comment: i don't know just can't registration !!

Comment: not the front log, the back one, connect to your server magento via terminal and run this `tail -f var/log/*` then try to save a customer